# I need to find a file *.sh from my directory and subdirectories and display them without Full Path

Tags: find

```
find . -iname "*.sh" | sed 's/[.]sh$//'
./backup/samukano/ex04/who_am_i
./backup/samukano/ex05/people
./days/day01/samukano/ex01/print_groups
./days/day01/samukano/ex02/find_sh
./samukano/ex04/who_am_i
./samukano/ex05/people
```

And I need just

```
who_am_i
people
...
people
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -iname "*.sh" -exec basename {} \; | sed s/\.sh//g
```

The `basename` utility removes all directory info from a path - relative or absolute.

The `dirname` utility does the opposite if needed.

Comment: Your `sed` command is worse than the OP's. See what it does to `what.a.shame.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Portable, not robust:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.Sh" -o -name "*.sH" -o -name "*.SH" \) |
sed -e 's|^.*/||' -e 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```

Robust, for parsing as null-terminated strings:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -printf "%f\0" | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```

Internally robust with possibly ambiguous output, for viewing:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -printf "%f\0" | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$/\n/'
```

---

---

## Full answer

There are many ways, some more robust than others. Plus the tools you may want to use have overlapping abilities, many of them are non-POSIX though, so you may or may not have the required options.

Additionally any directory of file name may contain newlines and other strange characters. For this reason, to parse filenames in a robust way you'd like to treat them as null terminated strings.

Then you may want to print the result as newline-terminated (i.e. regular) strings anyway for human-readability (risking ambiguous output though).

Tools usually support null-terminated strings with non-POSIX extensions.

---

E.g. to get rid of these full paths that are the main issue, you can use:

- `find . -printf "%f"`, but your `find` may or may not support `-printf`;
- or `basename`;
- or even `sed`.

To strip `.sh` you can use:

- `basename path_to_process .sh`, but it's case sensitive and I guess you used `-iname` for a reason (note `-iname` is not required by POSIX);
- or `sed` (like you did), which can be made case-insensitive.

This analysis is not exhaustive.

---

The most robust, case-insensitive version returns null-terminated strings. This makes the output fully reliable for further parsing:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -printf "%f\0" | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```

The same, returning human-readable and possibly ambiguous output:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -printf "%f\0" | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$/\n/'
```

The ambiguity manifests itself like this:

```
foo
bar
```

Were there two scripts: `foo.sh` and `bar.sh`? or just one `foo(newline here)bar.sh`?

It will get even more confusing if you cannot use `sed -z` and must provide input to `sed` as newline-terminated strings. In this case a single file `foo.sh(newline here)bar.sh` will also generate the above output.

What if your `sed` supports `-z` but `find` doesn't support `-printf`? Maybe your `basename` supports `-z`. This should be fully robust:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec basename -z -a {} + | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```

or without the support for `-a`:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec basename -z {} \; | sed -z 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```

I can see your `find` does support `-iname`, it might not though. What if it didn't? Quite naive but working approach:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.Sh" -o -name "*.sH" -o -name "*.SH" \) ...
```

As you can see it all depends on available options.

---

Finally let's suppose your paths use a *safe set* of printable characters (no newlines etc.). This command should be *portable* and good enough:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.Sh" -o -name "*.sH" -o -name "*.SH" \) |
sed -e 's|^.*/||' -e 's/[.][sS][hH]$//'
```